# How to sort List<object>?

Tags: c#

I have a List as follow:

```
 List<object> _l = new List<object>();

_l.Add(new {
    Period = _period,
    Ref_No = _ref_no,
    Status = _status,
    Status_Text = _status_text,
    Message = _message
});
```

The status value would be 0,1 or 2

I don't want to use a Class, How to sort by Status?

Need help

Thanks a lot in advance

Don

Comment: Why do you not want to use a class?

Comment: "I don't want to use a Class" What do you think `List<object>` is?

Comment: I have too many class, I just want to use an object.. is it possible?

Comment: Instead of an anonymous class why not use a value tuple (if you're in C#8) `List<(int Period, int Ref_No, int Status, string Status_Text, string Message)>`?  Or a `List<Tuple<int, int, int, string, string>>` if you're not in C# 8

Comment: Or another option is `List<dynamic>` if you want to use an anonymous class, but note that has performance issues and will result in errors that would typically be caught at compile time failing at run time instead.

Comment: What makes you think you have too many classes?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461479/sort-list-by-field-c  That question is about a list containing a known type.  This is a list of anonymous classes cast to `object`.  You cannot access the properties without reflection since you don't know the type to cast the `object` too and obviously `object` does not contain the property they want to sort on.

Comment: How *many* classes is too many?

Comment: anonymous types are meant as temporary data, mostly for use in LINQ queries. Once you convert it to a object there is no good way to access the properties. The primary alternatives are: a) Create a new class. b) Use a Tuple. c) Use a ValueTuple

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp - pretty subjective matter, for one 2 classes are to much, for the other 2000, for the other there is no too many if you need them use them

Comment: @juharr Value tuples were introduced in C# 7, IIRC

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, my mistake and too late to fix.

Comment: Change the declaration to `List<dynamic> _l = new List<object>();` and the sort using `_l.Sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.Status.CompareTo(obj2.Status));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function to do it

```
 public List<Object> SortLST(string SDirection, string propertie, List<Object> data)
    {

        List<Object> data_sorted = new List<Object>();

        if (SDirection == "Ascending")
        {
            data_sorted = (from n in data
                           orderby GetDynamicSortProperty(n, propertie) ascending
                           select n).ToList();
        }
        else if (SDirection == "Descending")
        {
            data_sorted = (from n in data
                           orderby GetDynamicSortProperty(n, propertie) descending
                           select n).ToList();

        }

        return data_sorted;

    }

    public object GetDynamicSortProperty(object item, string propName)
    {
        //Use reflection to get order type
        return item.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(item, null);
    }
```